# how to detect rectangle shape object using python

Tags: python, opencv

I am doing a project in python.I want to detect rectangle shape object by opening the webcam using python.I had tried it but I didn't get accurate Answer.I show the object in front of webcam If any finger touched our object it doesn't recognize our object.please anyone can help me.Thanks in Advance:)
Here is my code: 
py:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import cv2

#dictionary of all contours
contours = {}
#array of edges of polygon
approx = []
#scale of the text
scale = 2
#camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
print("press q to exit")

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

#calculate angle
def angle(pt1,pt2,pt0):
    dx1 = pt1[0][0] - pt0[0][0]
    dy1 = pt1[0][1] - pt0[0][1]
    dx2 = pt2[0][0] - pt0[0][0]
    dy2 = pt2[0][1] - pt0[0][1]
    return float((dx1*dx2 + dy1*dy2))/math.sqrt(float((dx1*dx1 + dy1*dy1))*(dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2) + 1e-10)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    #Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        #grayscale
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        #Canny
        canny = cv2.Canny(frame,80,240,3)

        #contours
        canny2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(canny,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        for i in range(0,len(contours)):
            #approximate the contour with accuracy proportional to
            #the contour perimeter
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contours[i],cv2.arcLength(contours[i],True)*0.02,True)

            #Skip small or non-convex objects
            if(abs(cv2.contourArea(contours[i]))<100 or not(cv2.isContourConvex(approx))):
                continue

            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[i])
            vtc = len(approx)
            if(vtc==4):
                cv2.putText(frame,'RECTANGLE',(x,y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,scale,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

        #Display the resulting frame
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        cv2.imshow('canny',canny)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 1048689: #if q is pressed
            break

#When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is my output:

**Non Working output**

[image: first object output]

**Working output**

[image: Another object Output]

Comment: Some example input and output would help to understand the problem.

Comment: Are you want me to post my output?

Comment: What I mean, is that you can post a picture of a working case and what that does not work. This way it is easy to see what can be improve in the image to work in all cases.

Comment: I got you ,I posted my output above

Comment: Can you got my problem ?

Comment: Yep, I see it now, so you are doing contours and then approx poly. The problem is that your finger changes the contour, then it can not be approximated  to 4 point contour. You could another approach, for instance with a line detector like hough transform, or maybe you can try to identify the rectangle in a different way, for example trying to fit a rectangle with your points (RANSAC perhaps) and then compare the area of the rectangle with the area of the contour, if similar is a rectangle, just with small deformations like the finger

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,My actual problem is  if any one shows their  mobile in front of webcam it should detect .I don't know how to train it thats why I tried  the above thing.please send me some solution to implement my idea

Comment: please anyone help me

Comment: a simple way of doing what I told you is to use [boundingRect](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontour#boundingrect) find the area of the contour and the area of the boundingRect. If both areas are similar (maybe 90% of the size) then it can be identified as a "rectangle" even if you have a finger.... You can also try machine learning algorithms

Comment: Thank you sir !...

Comment: I saw boundingRect which was send by you.can you edit my code and  explain to me because I am new to the concept

Answer (score 1):

You currently have this part in your code:

```
        #Skip small or non-convex objects
        if(abs(cv2.contourArea(contours[i]))<100 or not(cv2.isContourConvex(approx))):
            continue

        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[i])
        vtc = len(approx)
        if(vtc==4):
            cv2.putText(frame,'RECTANGLE',(x,y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,scale,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
```

here it is possible to create a rectangle around the contour and compare the areas. For that it is possible to use boundingRect, however, your phone can be slightly angled, so minAreaRect is better for this. It will return `((x,y), (w,h), angle)` you care is the (w,h) part since the area is `w*h`. You already know hot to get the actual area of the contour, since it is in your code.

At the end the code should look like this:

```
        #Skip small or non-convex objects
        if(abs(cv2.contourArea(contours[i]))<100 or not(cv2.isContourConvex(approx))):
            continue

        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[i])
        vtc = len(approx)
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[i])
        rectArea = rect[1][0] * rect[1][1]
        contourArea = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
        # now it will check if the difference is less than 10% of the rect area
        if vtc==4 or abs(rectArea - contourArea) < rectArea * .10:
            cv2.putText(frame,'RECTANGLE',(x,y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,scale,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
```

Probably this will work, but you may need to adjust the threshold (I used 10% of rectArea). Even the 4 point check can be omitted, If it is a rectangle it will have a perfect fit (rectarea-contourarea) = 0.

I hope this helps, however this is a simple way. More possible answers are also valid for this. You can even think it with machine learning algorithms, or rectangle fitting algorithms.

Comment: Thank your sir !...for your reply and explanation.

Comment: Sir ,I have a doubt is it possible to detect only mobile phones using any simple way.I don't aware of training the objects.

Comment: Please help me !...sir

Comment: sir,After I edited my code as you  said for all the object  I am getting output as rectangle .If I show a pen it detected as rectangle.

Comment: With this it detects rectangular like objects.... everything that can be fitted in a rectangle and that it covers most of the rectangle. The other way is to do line detections with hough transforms.... but for classification problems you should look for a machine learning approach

Comment: I saw some of the  machine learning approach sir !...It is difficult to do Can you help me to detect mobile object using python and opencv

Comment: when I show mobile device infront of webcam .It will show mobile device is detected

Comment: Sorry @sara, that is not so simple. First you have a lot of techniques for image classification and object detection and all of them requires a lot of fine tuning of the parameters or training for it to work correctly for your case.  I would recommend to start step by step, read several tutorials and try to adjust some samples to your case.

Comment: ohh !..Thank you sir !..I will follow your guidance

Comment: Sir ,Do you aware of  detecting cell phone using tensorflow object Detection API